# json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php

I have output object class from query like this,

```
$so_result = stdClass#14 {
    "colorname" => "Silver"
  , "colorgroupname" => "MEDIUM SILVER"
  , "colorcode" => "1D4"
  , "brand" => null
};


echo json_decode($so_result,true);
```

and i use json for append into div modal when user click and the modal show with the result

this my ajax to call and append the result.

```
$.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                datatype:"json",
                url:"",
                data:data,
                cache:false,
                success: function(data) {
                        $('#color').append(data);
                }
            });
```

how make the result can show.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I regret to inform you that `json_decode()` is not a JavaScript function.

Comment: Read the error message. You are passing a stdClass object to a place which expects a string.

Comment: You should use `json_encode` not `json_decode`.

Comment: @Vohuman, thankyou i i change to json_encode and its work but how to show the result using php tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
$so_result = (object) [
    "colorname" => "Silver",
    "colorgroupname" => "MEDIUM SILVER",
    "colorcode" => "1D4",
    "brand" => null
];


echo json_encode($so_result,true);
```

And the javascript

```
$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     datatype:"json",
     url:"",
     data:data,
     cache:false,
     success: function(data) {
         $('#color').append(data.colorname);
     }
 });
```